# How to add days to today on a Google Query?

Tags: google-query-language

Using [Google Query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) language, how do I properly add days to today?

I tried the below but if fails with an error.

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I, K, M, N, R, AF, W WHERE
toDate(A) >= DATE '2021-12-16' and
toDate(A) <= DATE TEXT((TODAY()+15),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Error:

```
Google Sheets: Invalid query: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "toDate" "toDate "" at line 3, column 1. Was expecting: "(" ...
```

Comment: Regarding your question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154103/18147, some policy has changed and it should now be eligible to be reopened. Do you want to cast a reopen vote so that we can try to reopen it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=query( A:AF ,"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I, K, M, N, R, AF, W  WHERE
TODATE(A) >= DATE'2021-12-16' and
TODATE(A) <= DATE'"&TEXT((TODAY()+15),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ")
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly not working, Mike. I am getting this error: `Google Sheets: Invalid query: Invalid date literal ["&TEXT((TODAY()+15),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd.`

Comment: I have added a screen shot to show how I test it and it works for me. Can you provide your ows sheet?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working by replacing today with now() as stated here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage